# OpenLayers3 and GeoJSON data with null features

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I am new to OpenLayers and I'm trying to label features on a map using a GeoJSON data. Here is my code:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ(),
        url: "http://abcd.com/cities/{z}/{x}/{y}.geojson"
    })
})
```

Sometimes I get **"features": null** in the GeoJSON data:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": null }
```

and features parsing fails with error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null**. Is it possible to replace **null** by **[]** before parsing features?

**UPDATE.** I found a solution, but got a new issue: I can't add features to the source. Here is my code (I'm using OpenLayers 3.9.0):

```
var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var source = new ol.source.TileVector({
    tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ(),
    tileLoadFunction: function (url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (XMLHttpRequest.DONE === xhr.readyState && 200 === xhr.status) {
                var json = xhr.responseText.replace("null", "[]");
                var features = format.readFeatures(json, {
                    featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
                });
                features.forEach(function (f) {
                    console.log(f.getGeometry().getCoordinates()); // features are parsed correctly
                });
                source.addFeatures(features);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    },
    url: "http://abcd.com/cities/{z}/{x}/{y}.geojson"
});
source.on("addfeature", function () {
    console.log(source.getFeatures()); // outputs an empty array of the features; it seems that the features haven't been added
});
new ol.Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: source
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
        maxZoom: 12,
        minZoom: 1,
        zoom: 6
    })
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for OpenLayers 3.9.0:

```
var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var source = new ol.source.TileVector({
    tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ(),
    tileLoadFunction: function (url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            try {
                var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if (!json.features) {
                    json.features = [];
                }
                var features = mapFormat.readFeatures(json, {
                    featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
                });
                callback(features);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    },
    url: "http://abcd.com/cities/{z}/{x}/{y}.geojson"
});
new ol.Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: source
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
        maxZoom: 12,
        minZoom: 1,
        zoom: 6
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please don't use OpenLayers 3.9 and `ol.source.TileVector`. That has many issues. Use a recent version and `ol.source.VectorTile`, like in your first snippet.

If your GeoJSON has `"features": null`, then it is is invalid. From the [GeoJSON spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-collection-objects):

> An object of type "FeatureCollection" must have a member with the name "features". The value corresponding to "features" is an array. Each element in the array is a feature object as defined above.

So if a tile has no features, the GeoJSON for the tile should contain `"features": []` instead.

If you do not have access to the server that provides the tiles, you can work around the issue on the client side:

```
new ol.source.VectorTile({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ(),
  url: "http://abcd.com/cities/{z}/{x}/{y}.geojson"
  tileLoadFunction: function(tile, url) {
    tile.setLoader(function() {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.onload = function() {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (json.features === null) {
          json.features = [];
        }
        var features = tile.getFormat().readFeatures(json, {featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()});
        tile.setFeatures(features);
      }
      xhr.send();
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but, unfortunately, your code doesn't work for me with latest 3.14: I get two errors (**Uncaught TypeError: this.s is not a function** and **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined**). The reason I use 3.9 is that the features are cut off with VectorTile since version 3.12 or higher.

Comment: I updated the code in my answer. It should work now. What do you mean by "features are cut off"? They are, but you should not see it because they are also drawn on adjacent tiles.

Comment: now I get error **TypeError: tile.setProjection is not a function(…)**, and if I comment `tile.setProjection(...);`, then I get error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined**. As for "features are cut off": please, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719478/vector-labels-get-cutted-since-new-ol-version-3-12-1-and-vectortile-layer).

Comment: I updated the answer so it should work now, like in your working solution below. Regarding cut off features, see my comment in the linked question. Or do like tsauerwein suggested, using ol.layer.Vector.

Comment: Please, see my comment above: your code doesn't work with the letest 3.14.1. I found [this issue](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/4678) and, I think, it explains why `tile.setFeatures(...)` throws an exception. As for cutt off features: buffering doesn't solve my problem (ie. setting `renderBuffer` to 512).

Comment: Sorry for that, the fix for the issue you mentioned should have been in the latest release, but it isn't fixed yet. Will probably be in 3.15. Regarding buffering, you need to do that when you generate your tiles, not by setting renderBuffer in OpenLayers.

Comment: No need to apologize and thanks for your great work and support. Unfortunately, I can't find any info how to use a buffer to generate vector tiles. Could you please to provide an example (e.g. jsfiddle)?

Comment: First you'll have to let us know what tool you used to create the tiles, and then someone will likely be able to show you how to configure that tool to add a buffer.

Comment: Well, I'd rather use the ol-3.9. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for OpenLayers 3.13.0:

```
new ol.Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.VectorTile({
            source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ(),
                url: "http://abcd.com/cities/{z}/{x}/{y}.geojson",
                tileLoadFunction: function(tile, url) {
                    tile.setLoader(function() {
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.open("GET", url);
                        xhr.onload = function () {
                            try {
                                var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                                if (!json.features) {
                                    json.features = [];
                                }
                                var features = tile.getFormat().readFeatures(json, {
                                    featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
                                });
                                tile.setFeatures(features);
                            } catch (e) {
                                console.log(e);
                            }
                        };
                        xhr.send();
                    });
                }
            })
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
        maxZoom: 12,
        minZoom: 1,
        zoom: 6
    })
});
```